# Python: How to copy a list of a dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

Python 3. I'm trying to copy a list of a dictionaries without altering the original list. This doesn't seem to work the same way that copying a list does:

List of Dictionaries

```
list_of_dict = [{"A":"a", "B": "b"}]    
table_copy = list(list_of_dict)
for x in table_copy:
    x['B'] = 1

print(list_of_dict)
print(table_copy)
```

Yields

```
[{'A': 'a', 'B': 1}]
[{'A': 'a', 'B': 1}]
```

For reference this is how copying a list looks like this:

```
orig_list = [1,2,3]
copy_list = list(orig_list)
copy_list[1] = "a"
print(orig_list)
print(copy_list)
```

Yields what we expect

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 'a', 3]
```

How do you actually copy a list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the line of code, `table_copy = list(list_of_dict)` you are creating a new 
*pointer (variable)* but the underlying elements are not copied (which is shallow copy)

```py
list_of_dict = [{"A":"a", "B": "b"}]    
table_copy = list(list_of_dict)

id(list_of_dict)
Out[8]: 2208287332232

id(table_copy)
Out[9]: 2208275740680

id(list_of_dict[0])
Out[10]: 2208275651624

id(table_copy[0])
Out[11]: 2208275651624 <== equal to id(list_of_dict[0])
```

You should use the [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) module from the standard library which comes with two useful functions

> **copy(x):**
>
> Return a shallow copy of x.
>
> **deepcopy(x):**
>
> Return a deep copy of x.

For your problem,

```py
from copy import deepcopy

list_of_dict = [{"A":"a", "B": "b"}]    
table_copy   = deepcopy(list_of_dict)
```

The thumb rule is to use, **deepcopy** when you have a complex object i.e. object containing other objects.

From the **docs**,

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound
>   objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):
>
> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent 
>   possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
>
> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts 
>   copies into it of the objects found in the original.

Comment: Oh thanks! I've never heard of deep copy before. This works for me!

Answer (score 3):

A very easy way is to do a `copy.deepcopy()`. It onstructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

```
import copy

list_of_dict = [{"A":"a", "B": "b"}]    
table_copy = copy.deepcopy(list_of_dict)

print(list_of_dict)
print(table_copy)

for x in table_copy:
    x['B'] = 1

print()
print(list_of_dict)
print(table_copy)
```

Output:

```
[{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b'}]
[{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b'}]

[{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b'}]
[{'A': 'a', 'B': 1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
list_of_dict = [{"A":"a", "B": "b"}]    
table_copy = list(d.copy() for d in list_of_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the deepcopy() of copy module.

> [Deep Copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)
>
> A deep copy creates a new object and recursively adds the copies of
>   nested objects present in the original elements.

```
In [15]: import copy

In [16]: list_of_dict
Out[16]: [{'A': 23, 'B': 'b'}]

In [18]: table_copy=copy.deepcopy(list_of_dict)

In [19]: table_copy
Out[19]: [{'A': 23, 'B': 'b'}]

In [20]: table_copy[0]['A']=2

In [21]: table_copy
Out[21]: [{'A': 2, 'B': 'b'}]

In [22]: list_of_dict
Out[22]: [{'A': 23, 'B': 'b'}]
```

[For More](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/shallow-deep-copy)

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a new list just by basing it off of another, so you have to do something like this:

```
list = ['foo','fib']
duplicate = list[:]
```

Now, if you try to append something to 'list', it won't show up in 'duplicate'. However, if you were to do `list = ['a','b']; duplicate = list`, then it would also show up in 'duplicate'.
If you try it with dictionaries, it also works.

```
list = [{1:1},{0:0}]
dupe = list[:]
list.append('e')
print list
print dupe
```

would give you this output:

```
[{1:1},{0:0},'e']
[{1:1},{0:0}]
```

EDIT: I have tried this in both 2 and 3 and it still works in either version.